# Match text after colon

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I want to match the word after the "type :".

What I have?

**My actual pattern**:
(?<=type\s:\s)(\w*)

**Text**:
"type : text,"

It work exact as I want when I have just one whitespace before/after color...

"type_SPACE_:_SPACE_text

But if I have 2 spaces or none, it doesn't work.

I already try with this, but doesn't match.
(?<=type\s*:\s*)(\w*)

Also, I try with this, best approach. But with this, the matched text contain the colon.

(?<=type)(\s*):(\s*)(.*)(?=,)

To do the test I use gskinner's tester...
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing this in C# and using the included Regex engine, your original regex should work, with a slight modification:

```
        string myString = "type :  something";

        var match = Regex.Match(myString, @"(?<=type\s*:\s*)\w+");

        Console.Write(match);
```

Edit: The reason why the `?<=type\s*:\s*)\w*` version wasn't working for you with multiple spaces, is because the regex match was happily returning various combinations of strings with 0 characters after the variable number of spaces following the colon.

You can view the various matched strings by using `Regex.Matches`, you'll see that your matched word is in there, but it's not the first result.

Comment: Magic, I'm still a little bit puzzled why your original `(?<=type\s*:\s*)\w*` doesn't work, I'm assuming it's happy with matching the `\w` 0 times, but I thought the greedy match would take care of that =O